# Can you bound the step size returned by scipy.optimize.line_search()?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I was under the impression that the `amax` parameter in [scipy.optimize.line_search](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.line_search.html) could bound the step size but it doesn't seem to work every time.

I know that I can bound the step size afterwards but I would prefer to be able to directly use all the returned values.